# Unable to hide y axis line in a stacked bar graph

Tags: java, hide, jfreechart, stacked-chart, yaxis

I am trying to hide the y axis line in my stacked bar chart in JFreeChart, and I have already tried below methods:

```
Setoutlinepaint(null)
Setbackgroundpaint(color.white)
Setoutlinevisible(false)
Categoryaxis.setaxislinevisible(false)
Categoryaxis.setvisible(false)
```

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Invoking the parent method [`setAxisLineVisible()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/Axis.html#setAxisLineVisible-boolean-) appears to produce the expected result for either a `CategoryAxis` or a `ValueAxis`. Starting from this [example](https://github.com/jfree/jfree-demos/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jfree/chart/demo/BarChartDemo1.java), the following changes in `createChart()` produce the result shown. I've changed the plot orientation to make the domain axis vertical, and I've invoked `setAxisLineVisible(false)` on both axes.

```
CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();
plot.setOrientation(PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL);
CategoryAxis domainAxis = plot.getDomainAxis();
domainAxis.setAxisLineVisible(false);
plot.setDomainAxis(domainAxis);
NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
rangeAxis.setAxisLineVisible(false);
rangeAxis.setStandardTickUnits(NumberAxis.createIntegerTickUnits());
```

Axis lines not visible:

[image: new chart]

Axis lines visible:

[image: old chart]

Note that the [factory methods](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.java) for both bar chart stacked  bar chart use the same axes.